# How to implement a Facebook login with LWC?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, canvas, facebook, auth

I am building a solution that lets users access their data on Facebook (like Pages/Ads/Feeds etc).

For this, we need to let the users login to their Facebook account while they are in Salesforce (from a custom tab)

I initially wholly went in the route of a canvas application, but due to the nature of jsforce being not wholly owned and supported by Salesforce, I dropped that path in favour of importing all the control over to Salesforce natively, and only making API calls using Salesforce data to our node webserver that can then handle the requests.

But the problem I now encountered was that Facebook does not have a downloadable Javascript SDK that one can use as a static resource and refer in the component. This SDK has standard APIs that can be used to login and other functionality. I am only concerned about the login and getting access token for the users to continue their activities.

These users are regular Sales folks who need to access data in the org like Accounts/Opportunities/Leads etc

I am trying to build a solution that can leverage Facebook SDKs (a third party JS library) within my LWC without a download. Or a solution that users of my org can use to login to their Facebook, and get a access token (handled by our service).

The path of canvas is open, though as a last option, as that would need to be done in Aura and would need to be maintained as it is, and might cause issues when we go into a full LWC org.

Any suggestions on how to implement either a custom Login or a way to reference the Facebook resource in my LWC?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish? Please edit your question with more details. If you haven't seen it,  [Social SSO](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/identity_external/identity_external_social) trailhead covers the 'traditional' method of signing into SF with your Facebook account.

Comment: Hi @identigral, added more details

Comment: Login with Facebook to Salesforce sounds like a possible option. Can't remember if out of the box Facebook auth provider lets you grab FB's token but you can give that a shot. If that doesn't work, you can roll your own, custom auth provider that will grab the token and store it somewhere so you can use it for subsequent calls into FB.